# Looker/Google Data Studio - blending two tables (missing values, also null)

Tags: looker-studio

**1. DATA**
I have a following source data in [Google Sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17N9WdFPsicYmzUbdAr6gTx-CsfmZ4Qmx0KxCTDzMl7Y/edit?usp=sharing):

| CALENDAR_FULL_DATE | MATERIAL_GROUP | MATERIAL | STORAGE_LOCATION | CATEGORY | QUANTITY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 September 2022 | AAAAA | 11111 | 121 | CONSUMPTION | 64 |
| 1 September 2022 | AAAAA | 11111 | 122 | CONSUMPTION | 1 |
| 1 September 2022 | AAAAA | 33333 | 124 | CORRECTION | 66 |
| 1 September 2021 | AAAAA | 33333 | 152 | CORRECTION | 29 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

**2. EXPECTED RESULT**
In [Looker/Google Data Studio](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/d87229be-185b-441d-b1c9-f44ee0c03cf2) I would like to create a following pivot table (and then play around with graphs, heat maps etc):

| MATERIAL_GROUP | MATERIAL | CONSUMPTION | CORRECTION | RATIO |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AAAAA | 11111 | 65 |  | 0% |
| AAAAA | 33333 | 628 | 341 | 54% |
| AAAAA | 44444 | 29 | 134 | 462% |
| AAAAA | 55555 |  | 86 | 0% |
| AAAAA | 66666 |  | 34 | 0% |
| AAAAA | 77777 |  | 121 | 0% |
| BBBBB | 99999 | 234 | 339 | 145% |

**3) Chart: Configuration + Setup** In my dashboard you can see that I created two tables (one with category = correction and another one with category = consumption). Then I blended and created a calculated field to obtain a ratio.

**4) Issue: Attempt at solving + Output**

a) I am missing some SKUs (understandably, because there is no 2-way-match in the blend for some SKUs, e.g. SKU 55555)

b) When calculating errors, I would like to see "0" instead of "null" (e.g. SKU 11111). Similarly, if there is an error (dividing by non-existing number, e.g. SKU 55555"), I would also like to see "0".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added Solution in page 2 of your [dashboard](https://datastudio.google.com/u/0/reporting/d87229be-185b-441d-b1c9-f44ee0c03cf2/page/p_4t5zi3vvzc)

trick is to use [COALESCE](https://www.sumified.com/google-data-studio-coalesce-function-examples) function in both the dimensions MATERIAL_GROUP and MATERIAL

[image]